# How to append data to table A from table B but only when table C has records in it

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I was hoping you could tell me what I’m doing wrong here.  I have the following excerpt from my Postgres Function: The part where I input into "RawdataCsvs2 does not work correctly.

I only want to insert records into StationMactemp and RawdataCsvs2 if the Venue is marked as “New” in the “CalcType” field of the “Venues” table.

When I run the script on venues that are not marked as “New” in the “CalcType” field, I get no records in the.StationMacTemp table (which is perfect and what I would expect) but for some reason I get records added to the RawdataCsv2 table even though I've also tried using the where clause

```
where "StationMacTemp"."CalcType" = 'New' 
   and "csv_file"."StationMac" in (Select "StationMac" 
                                   from dbo."StationMacTemp");
```

I thought if I put in the criteria that the StationMac has to be found in the StationMacTemp table then if there are no records in that table then no records should get added to the RawDataCsvs2 table but they still are and I don’t know why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was hoping I could use an If statement in my function or maybe a Case When and this would limit this script to only run when a Venue in the Venues table is marked as "New" in the “CalcType” field.

I've tried but no luck and I keep thinking I should be able to do this with a Where clause alone.  I have noticed that if I try this in reverse and I choose a Venue that is marked as "New" then both the "StationMacTemp" and "RawDataCsvs2" table get populated as they should.

```
...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo."StationMacTemp";
create table dbo."StationMacTemp" as 
select "StationMac","RawDataCsvs"."VenueId", "Venues"."CalcType", "AreaOfInterestId" 
from dbo."RawDataCsvs" 
   INNER JOIN dbo."Venues" ON ("Venues"."Id"= "RawDataCsvs"."VenueId")
   inner join dbo."AreaOfInterests" on ("AreaOfInterests"."Id"= "RawDataCsvs"."AreaOfInterestId")
where "Venues"."Id" = venueid 
  and "Venues"."CalcType" ='New' 
  and ("Venues"."VenueType" = 'RestoBar' OR "AreaOfInterests"."Level" = 77)  
group by dbo."RawDataCsvs"."StationMac", "RawDataCsvs"."VenueId", "Venues"."CalcType", dbo."RawDataCsvs"."AreaOfInterestId"; 


INSERT INTO dbo."RawDataCsvs2"("TimeStr", "StationMac", "Level", "Lat", "Lng", "RssMacStation1", 
        "RssStation1", "RssMacStation2", "RssStation2", "RssMacStation3", 
        "RssStation3", "RssMacStation4", "RssStation4", "RssMacStation5", 
        "RssStation5", "RssMacStation6", "RssStation6", "RssMacStation7", 
        "RssStation7", "RssMacStation8", "RssStation8", "RssMacStation9", 
        "RssStation9", "RssMacStation10", "RssStation10", "LoadingGuid", 
        "LoadingDate",
        "SiteId", 
        "VenueId", 
        "LocalTime", "OperatingDay", "AreaOfInterestId")
SELECT "TimeStr", csv_file."StationMac", csv_file."Level", "Lat", "Lng", "RssMacStation1", 
       "RssStation1", "RssMacStation2", "RssStation2", "RssMacStation3", 
           "RssStation3", "RssMacStation4", "RssStation4", "RssMacStation5", 
           "RssStation5", "RssMacStation6", "RssStation6", "RssMacStation7", 
           "RssStation7", "RssMacStation8", "RssStation8", "RssMacStation9", 
           "RssStation9", "RssMacStation10", "RssStation10", "LoadingGuid", 
           "LoadingDate",
        dbo.csv_file."SiteId", 
        csv_file."VenueId", 
        "LocalTime", "OperatingDay", dbo."StationMacTemp"."AreaOfInterestId" as "AreaOfInterestId"
FROM dbo.csv_file
    INNER JOIN dbo."Venues" ON ("Venues"."Id"= csv_file."VenueId")
    INNER JOIN dbo."StationMacTemp" on ("StationMacTemp"."StationMac" = csv_file."StationMac")
    INNER JOIN dbo."AreaOfInterests" on ("AreaOfInterests"."Id"= "StationMacTemp"."AreaOfInterestId")
where "Venues"."Id" = venueid 
  and "Venues"."CalcType" ='New' 
  and ("Venues"."VenueType" = 'RestoBar' OR "AreaOfInterests"."Level" = 77);
```

I would expect that if the Venue is marked as "New" in the Venues table that both the StationMacTemp and RawDataCsvs2 tables will be populated and if a venue is not marked as "New" then both table would not be populated.  I'm not getting any error messages I'm just always getting the RawDataCsvs2 table populated regardless of whether the Venue is "New" or not

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it (and I personally think they make reading a SQL statement **much** harder)

Comment: I don't understand why you create that "temp" table in the first place? Why don't you join `RawDataCsvs` to `Venues` and `AreaOfInterests` in the main query? I think you can get rid of the "temp" table and only use a single INSERT statement: http://dpaste.com/0K1X7BT